# Find substring in string compared to list

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, if-statement

I am using python to create a quiz for a school project. I want to have a list of names and question answers that people cannot input. (BC they are inappropriate). Whenever i use the code i have now, it says that any input is one of the blocked ones. I am using an in-browser editor(No pip installations are available to me).

This is my code. I have the list of blocked strings in a variable called "Banned" At first this piece of code worked, but eventually when anyone played it, the code would block all inputs, not just the ones in the Banned list.

```
import os
import random
print("No Capitals!")

cheatcode = ""
randlist = ["Shiny Cupcake","Good Puppy","Sunshine","Pretty Painting","Happy Trees","Soft Kitten","in love","starstuck"]
randname = random.randrange(0,6)
playscore = 0
question = 0
idkbanned = ["idk","na","n/a","urmom","ur mom","yourmom","your mom","duh"]
banned = ["ur","mom","your mom","yourmom","daddy"]
notallowed = ("Warning, Idk, N/A and duh are not allowed, answering as ""your mom"" is obnoxious")
playname = input("What is your preferred name? ")
playername = (str.lower(playname))
if playername == ("sudo su"):
    playername = "{@root}"
    pset = input("Set Points? ")
    if pset == "y":
        points = input("Points ")
        point = int(points)
        playscore = point
    dev = input("question ")
    question = int(dev)
#elif [x for x in banned if x in playername]:
 #   print("Yeah, NO" + "  Nice try...deducting 20 points for stupidity")
  #  playscore -= 20
   # playername = randlist[randname]
elif playername == cheatcode:
    print("Nice!")
    print("Score:")
    print("300")
    playscore += 300
    playername = ("Superuser")
    playscore -= 300
else:
    question = 0
enc = ["you can do this","never doubt yourself","good effort","almost"]
incorrectnum = random.randrange(0,3)
questions = [
    "What does the prime meridian run through",
    "what kind of orbit draws a line through a majority of the 7 wonders of the ancient world", "what is the largest metropoitan area in the world that does not body water?","The Kaliningrad oblast borders what body of water", "What country has the lowest people per square mile?","how many time zones does russia span?", "what does AMS stand for","T/F:mount everest is the tallest point on earth","T/F:australia is narrower than the moon","What are citizens of Sudan called","Does Japan's traffic run on the left or right"]
answers = [
    ["england","observatory","royal observatory"],
    ["two day","two","2"], "johannesburg","baltic sea", "namibia", "11", "accelerator mass spectrometry", ["false","f"],["false","f"],"sudanese","left"
]
idkount = 0

print("Hello, " + playername)

qai1n = input(questions[question] + "? ")
if qai1n in answers[question]:
    print("correct")
    playscore += 10
    print("score:  ")
    print(playscore)
    question += 1

elif qai1n in idkbanned:
    idkount += 1
    if idkount > 3:
        print("No more IDK, N/A, or your mom, " + playername + " You are stalling")
    elif idkount > 3:
        print(notallowed + ", " + playername)
        playscore -= 10
        question += 1
else:
    print("Wrong, but " + enc[incorrectnum])
    question += 1
   
qai2n = input(questions[question] + "? ")
if qai2n in answers[question]:
    print("correct")
    playscore += 10
    print("score:  ")
    print(playscore)
    question += 1

elif qai2n in idkbanned:
    idkount += 1
    if idkount > 3:
        print("No more IDK, N/A, or your mom, " + playername + " You are stalling")
    elif idkount > 3:
        print(notallowed + ", " + playername)
        playscore -= 10
        question += 1
else:
    print("Wrong, but " + enc[incorrectnum])
    question += 1

qai3n = input(questions[question] + "? ")
if qai3n in answers[question]:
    print("correct")
    playscore += 10
    print("score:  ")
    print(playscore)
    question += 1
elif qai3n in idkbanned:
    idkount += 1
    if idkount > 3:
        print("No more IDK, N/A, or your mom, " + playername + " You are stalling")
    elif idkount > 3:
        print(notallowed + ", " + playername)
        playscore -= 10
        question += 1
else:
    print("Wrong, but " + enc[incorrectnum])
       
    question += 1

qai4n = input(questions[question] + "? ")
if qai4n in answers[question]:
    print("correct")
    playscore += 10
    print("score:  ")
    print(playscore)
    question += 1
elif qai4n in idkbanned:
    idkount += 1
    if idkount > 3:
        print("No more IDK, N/A, or your mom, " + playername + " You are stalling")
    elif idkount > 3:
        print(notallowed + ", " + playername)
        playscore -= 10
        question += 1
else:
    print("Wrong, but " + enc[incorrectnum])
       
    question += 1

qai5n = input(questions[question] + "? ")
if qai5n in answers[question]:
    print("correct")
    playscore += 10
    print("score:  ")
    print(playscore)
    question += 1
elif qai5n in idkbanned:
    idkount += 1
    if idkount > 3:
        print("No more IDK, N/A, or your mom, " + playername + " You are stalling")
    elif idkount > 3:
        print(notallowed + ", " + playername)
        playscore -= 10
        question += 1
else:
    print("Wrong, but " + enc[incorrectnum])
    question += 1
    
qai6n = input(questions[question] + "? ")
if qai6n in answers[question]:
    print("correct")
    playscore += 10
    print("score:  ")
    print(playscore)
    question += 1
elif qai6n in idkbanned:
    idkount += 1
    if idkount > 3:
        print("No more IDK, N/A, or your mom, " + playername + " You are stalling")
    elif idkount > 3:
        print(notallowed + ", " + playername)
        playscore -= 10
        question += 1
else:
    print("Wrong, but " + enc[incorrectnum])
    question += 1
qai7n = input(questions[question] + "? ")
if qai7n in answers[question]:
    print("correct")
    playscore += 10
    print("score:  ")
    print(playscore)
    question += 1
elif qai7n in idkbanned:
    idkount += 1
    if idkount > 3:
        print("No more IDK, N/A, or your mom, " + playername + " You are stalling")
    elif idkount > 3:
        print(notallowed + ", " + playername)
        playscore -= 10
        question += 1
else:
    print("Wrong, but " + enc[incorrectnum])
    question += 1
qai8n = input(questions[question] + "? ")
if qai8n in answers[question]:
    print("correct")
    playscore += 10
    print("score:  ")
    print(playscore)
    question += 1
elif qai8n in idkbanned:
    idkount += 1
    if idkount > 3:
        print("No more IDK, N/A, or your mom, " + playername + " You are stalling")
    elif idkount > 3:
        print(notallowed + ", " + playername)
        playscore -= 10
        question += 1
else:
    print("Wrong, but " + enc[incorrectnum])
    question += 1
qai9n = input(questions[question] + "? ")
if qai9n in answers[question]:
    print("correct")
    playscore += 10
    print("score:  ")
    print(playscore)
    question += 1
elif qai9n in idkbanned:
    idkount += 1
    if idkount > 3:
        print("No more IDK, N/A, or your mom, " + playername + " You are stalling")
    elif idkount > 3:
        print(notallowed + ", " + playername)
        playscore -= 10
        question += 1
else:
    print("Wrong, but " + enc[incorrectnum])
    question += 1
qai10n = input(questions[question] + "? ")
if qai9n in answers[question]:
    print("correct")
    playscore += 10
    print("score:  ")
    print(playscore)
    question += 1
elif qai10n in idkbanned:
    idkount += 1
    if idkount > 3:
        print("No more IDK, N/A, or your mom, " + playername + " You are stalling")
    elif idkount > 3:
        print(notallowed + ", " + playername)
        playscore -= 10
        question += 1
else:
    print("Wrong, but " + enc[incorrectnum])
    question += 1
qai11n = input(questions[question] + "? ")
if qai11n in answers[question]:
    print("correct")
    playscore += 10
    print("score:  ")
    print(playscore)
    question += 1
elif qai11n in idkbanned:
    idkount += 1
    if idkount > 3:
        print("No more IDK, N/A, or your mom, " + playername + " You are stalling")
    elif idkount > 3:
        print(notallowed + ", " + playername)
        playscore -= 10
        question += 1
else:
    print("Wrong, but " + enc[incorrectnum])
    question += 1
qai12n = input(questions[question] + "? ")
if qai12n in answers[question]:
    print("correct")
    playscore += 10
    print("score:  ")
    print(playscore)
    question += 1
elif qai12n in idkbanned:
    idkount += 1
    if idkount > 3:
        print("No more IDK, N/A, or your mom, " + playername + " You are stalling")
    elif idkount > 3:
        print(notallowed + ", " + playername)
        playscore -= 10
        question += 1
else:
    print("Wrong, but " + enc[incorrectnum])
    question += 1
    
print("Score")
print(playscore)
```

This is what I get when using any name(A as an example)

Console: What is your preferred name? A Yeah, NO Nice try...deducting 20 points for stupidity Hello, Shiny Cupcake What does the prime meridian run through?

I have tried

if playername in list(Banned)

I know that my code is not DRY.

Comment: This is only a code fragment.  We can't run this.  Please share the whole code.

Comment: Done. I know that it is not dry.

Comment: Please use a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: In this code, the part that checks the banned list is commented out.  This cannot be the real code that is having the problem you describe.

Comment: Also, if I uncomment that section, I do not see the behavior you describe...

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment:

```
#elif [x for x in banned if x in playername]:
 #   print("Yeah, NO" + "  Nice try...deducting 20 points for stupidity")
  #  playscore -= 20
   # playername = randlist[randname]
```

And you'll have fixed it.

Comment: Doing this does not demonstrate the error that the OP claims.  Therefore the actual code must be different than what is shown.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct the *in* keywork is what you're looking for but your code is not in the best order

```
banned = ["ur","mom","your mom","yourmom"]
playername = input("your name")
if playername in banned:
   print("good try")
else:
   print("welcome "+playername)
```

you might also want to create a method to avoid repeating the same verification over and over again. A good way to stop the game from continuing is to raise an exception you migth want to check that concept but this will stop the execution

```
def checkProfanity(word):
if word in banned:
  raise Exception("No cursing")
```

Besides that this is not the best way to check for the presence of a string in the input.

```
for word in banned:
   if playername.__contains__(word):
      print("good try")
```

will also filter things like 'xxx mom xxx'

Comment: I see you're still editing the code. so this might not be as helpful with the whole script. Anyway you should really try putting that logic in methods

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Because this is a school project, I am also trying to detect if there is a shortening of a word in there, because I do not want to write profane words in a school project, even to ban them. Is there a way to find if the input string contains a certain substring from the list? From what I understand, this will do whole strings only. If not, thank you for your time.

Comment: the last script I shared in this answer is what you're looking for